# GhostScript - wrong font substitution (wrong characters)

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, ghostscript, truetype

I'm trying to convert pdf file to image.

Command: gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=cover.png -r144 myfile.pdf

Output:

```
Can't find CID font "MyStrangeNonEmbeddedFont".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /MyStrangeNonEmbeddedFont, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /some/path/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
```

Font is successfully substituted with DroidSansFallback.ttf, but all characters are incorrect. Examples:

```
'C' is substituted with '<'
'6' is substituted with '>'
'B' is substituted with '@'
'D' is substituted with 'B'
```

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you have some time left, please read the short introductory [tour] to familiarize yourself with Stack Overflow. Can you add a link to a downloadable PDF with which you are having this problem? That way we can at the very least check if the problem arises from the input file. You can [edit] your question to add a link.

Comment: blindly substituting is generally a bad idea. Just follow the [ghostscript advice](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution) and put the right candidate in the right directory and try again.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I did, using several different fonts (CID and fallback TFF). Characters are still wrong, but interestingly still the same way - "B" being "D" and so on.

Comment: this will happen if the Character ID mapping (the CID part for CID fonts) for the "replacement font" doesn't match the CID mapping used by the origin font. If it's a low number of cases, you *could* try to edit your target font and change its CID mapping manually (which is, honestly, a bit of a pain), or you can try to get a copy of the original font used

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, added as an answer instead.

This is why the PDF specification strongly suggests embedding CIDFonts.

Character code -> CID -> Glyph description is a complex area of the specification, more so than for regular fonts.

The only way you are going to get this correct is to use the original font that was not embedded. Your best bet to 'fix' this is to embed the font and make a new PDF file.

If you can't do that then you can source the font and add a specific entry to cidfmap.

Failing that then you can try editing the CMap in the PDF file (the CMap maps character codes to CIDs) or the character codes in the document, to match whatever font you have available (this is likely to be a lot of work).

The Ordering of the CIDSystemInfo 'might' give you some clues, you may be able to use the Registry and Ordering to determine how CIDs relate to actual glyphs.

If you have a genuine CIDFont to use as a substitute *might* be able to manipulate the CIDs of the glyphs, but that will be hard. If you are using a TrueType font as a substitute fro a CIDFont then you can't alter the CMap which Ghostscript will produce for that CIDFont.

Comment: Thanks, @KenS. There's something I don't understand - pdftotext is able to retrieve text from PDF just fine, so we can assume that ghostscript is able to understand text from PDF file. So, why it can't "just" write it using any "stupid" font or even plain text ("(whatever) show")?

Comment: You can't use a font, you have to use a CIDFont. Without seeing the file I couldn't even begin to guess at what exactly is going on, but you are assuming that the character code->CID for the font that is missing is the same as the character code->CID for the substituted font. That's likely not going to be true. We are substituting a TrueType font which means we have to map character code->CID and then do a further mapping from CID->GID (because TrueType fonts use GIDs). Now all that takes place behind the scenes, but its not too surprising that we choose a different set of CIDs for that font.

Comment: My guess would be that pdftotext is doing something 'dumb' like assuming the (original) character codes can be used as ASCII, whcih is plain wrong for CIDFonts, but it might work, sometimes. The only *reliable* way yo get 'text' back out of a PDF is if the font has an associated ToUnicode CMap which maps the character codes to Unicode code points. I'd venture to guess your original file does not, so basically all bets are off. You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using but I'd recommend trying the most up to date, we do make continual improvements.